# Is it possible to replicate Photoshop's Indexed Color dialog with ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to port a Photoshop Action to ImageMagick, and I'm having some trouble with the step where I need to reduce the number of colors to a specific palette.

In Photoshop, it's possible to use the `Indexed Color` option to define a limited palette of colors (in my case, 8 precisely chosen colors and 4 wildcard colors which Photoshop gets to choose based on the specifics of each image):

[image]

Note that the total number of colors is `12`, but the Forced Colors palette only defines `8` specific colors. (As mentioned above, there are 4 "wildcard colors" that Photoshop gets to choose.)

So, my two specific questions:

**1. Is it possible to replicate this forced palette + wildcard color functionality with ImageMagick?**

**2. What is the ImageMagick equivalent of `Dither: Diffusion` and `Amount: 30%`?** I've noticed the dithering results I get from Photoshop are much better than the dithering results I get from ImageMagick. I've played around with all sorts of IM dithering options, but I can't seem to get the same high quality results.

Comment: I suspect you would need to write your own ImageMagick add-on processing module to do this, but that is quite a lot of effort and not for the faint-hearted. My answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/29627240/2836621 ... is related.